# Memory Optimized Table With Some Terrible Response Time

Tags: t-sql, query-optimization, sql-server-2014, memory-optimized-tables

Replaced a large table with a memory optimized table
For some stuff I am getting good response time for some stuff it dies
It is a composite primary key
The only way I can get it to use the Primary Key is to search on a specific row (the entire PK)
Will NOT use the PK for sort or only one component of composite key
Sized the hash buckets from existing data

used the syntax in this link for the composite primary key
[Hekaton: Composite Primary Key in create table statement](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowshardware/en-US/9afca13d-09bb-4209-9554-5eff6df54e79/hekaton-composite-primary-key-in-create-table-statement)
[CREATE TABLE (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FTSindex]
(
    [sID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [wordPos] [int] NOT NULL,
    [wordID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [charPos] [int] NOT NULL,

INDEX [ix_wordID_MO_2] NONCLUSTERED HASH 
(
    [wordID]
)WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 524288),
CONSTRAINT [pk_FTSindexMO_2] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH 
(
    [sID],
    [wordPos]
)WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 268435456)
)WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON , DURABILITY = SCHEMA_ONLY )

select top 10 * from [FTSindex] where [sID] = 100
-- runs in 0 seconds 
-- Index Seek on ix_wordID_MO_2 
-- it is NOT using the PRIMARY KEY pk_FTSindexMO_2

select top 10 * from [FTSindex] where [wordPos] = 100
-- never finishes (I only waited 10 minutes) 
-- will not even display an execution plan

select top 10 * from [FTSindex] where [sID] = 100 and [wordPos] < 1000
-- never finishes (I only waited 10 minutes) 
-- will not even display an execution plan


select top 10 * from [FTSindex] order by [sID]
-- never finishes (I only waited 10 minutes) 
-- query plan is Table Scan 

select top 10 * from [FTSindex] order by [sID], [wordPos]
-- never finishes (I only waited 10 minutes) 
-- will not even display an execution plan

select top 10 * from [FTSindex] where [wordID] = 100 and [sID] = 856515 
-- runs in 0 seconds
-- Index Seek on ix_wordID_MO_2

select top 10 * from [FTSindex] where [wordID] = 100 and [sID] = 856515  and [wordPos] < 1000
-- never finishes (I only waited 10 minutes) 
-- will not even display an execution plan

select * from [FTSindex] where [sID] = 100  
-- 45 seconds to return 1500 rows 
-- table scan 

select * from [FTSindex] where [sID] = 100  and [wordPos] = 1133 
-- runs in 0 seconds
-- this uses the pk_FTSindexMO_2 
-- this is the only way I could get it to use the primary key
```

Note in the original (non memory optimized table)
All of these queries run in 0 seconds
I don't mean each
ALL run in 0 seconds

I think this summarizes my problem
[Troubleshooting Common Performance Problems with Memory-Optimized Hash Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589805%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

Not using HASH for Primary Key seems to have fixed it

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FTSindex]
(
    [sID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [wordPos] [int] NOT NULL,
    [wordID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [charPos] [int] NOT NULL,

INDEX [ix_wordID_MO_2] NONCLUSTERED HASH 
(
    [wordID]
)WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 524288),
CONSTRAINT [pk_FTSindexMO_2] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [sID] ASC,
    [wordPos] ASC
)
)WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON , DURABILITY = SCHEMA_ONLY )
```

Note in the end I whet back to the old disk based tables
In the actual queries used by the application memory optimized was slower
The memory optimized did load faster but this table  is write once and read many

Comment: You haven't mentioned how many records do you have.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan How does that matter?  A top 10 does not even run and it will not even display a query plan.  Like 200 million rows.  I stated I sized the buckets from existing data.

Comment: Try to use `OPTION (FAST 10)` hint and let me know about result.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan no difference on OPTION (FAST 10).  But I updated the question.  If I search on the entire PK then it will use the PK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hash indexes are not usable for range scans. Range indexes are.

Comment: I don't know what that means

Comment: A hash index allows you to get all rows that have exactly the given search keys. Not usable for sorting or scanning ranges of the index. See the docs.

Comment: But there is nothing called a range index.  I think you mean nonclustered index (without the hash).

Comment: Yip, looks like you need to go `NONCLUSTERED` or disk based for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133166(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Yeah, the name might be different in the syntax. In the technology papers they call it range index. It is supposed to be much slower (if that is relevant to you).

Comment: Much slower is better than not used.

Comment: @MarkD I needed to go NONCLUSTERED without the HASH.

Comment: My gutt feeling tells me that for RAM based tables clustered & non-clustered won't particularly matter... it is called Random Access Memory for a reason. Anyway, if this is a read-mostly table, then I don't see why you'd try to push (and keep) it into memory. Simply use a 'disk-based' table, make sure to have good indexes and make sure statistics are up to date (WITH FULLSCAN sometimes helps, depending on how you load the data defragging and partitioning might help too) and let the cache manage its own memory.

Comment: @deroby "memory-optimized" is not PINTABLE. Hekaton has lots of other changes. Might be worth looking into.

Comment: Hmm... I'll admit not having played around with it yet, but going by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx the documentation says: `"Memory-optimized tables are in memory user tables, the schema of which is persisted on disk similar to other user tables. Memory-optimized tables can be accessed from natively compiled stored procedures."` Maybe I'm reading too much into this so I'll take your advice and go through the rest of the documentation to get a better grasp on the concept. (PS: PINTABLE was deprecated so long ago I had completely forgotten about it =)